# Replace spans with inputs with the same text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create an "inline editor" for my profile-page, where I'm using ajax to update the users informations, but I have some problems I can't seem to fight.

I want to replace some spans with inputs with the same text inside, so that the user can edit his informations directly on the profile site.

I've found some scripts which works okay, but only when there is one span to replace. I need to replace multiple spans with inputs.

This is what I've tried this:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="name" class="editable">My name</span><br>
<span id="email" class="editable">My email</span>
<span class="edit">Edit</span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {

    $(this).text("Change").attr('class', 'change');
    $('span.editable').replaceWith($('<input type=text>').attr({ id: 'name', value: $('span.editable').text() }));

});

$(document).on('click', '.change', function() {

    $(this).text("Edit").attr('class', 'edit');
    // Do Ajax Call

});
```

It works, somehow, but the text in the inputs are all the same, which is not intended. I need the correct text from each spans to be put, in each input.

I also need someway to identify the inputs, so the new values will be stored correctly using an AJAX call, but i don't know how to identify them. Should I use ID or NAME?

I hope you can understand my question and that someone can/will help me with this. I would really appreciate that.

- Thanks Martin

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H2RPy/)

Edit fiddle - JSFiddle
jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the version of `replaceWith` that accepts a function:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wb74k/

```
$('span.editable').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<input type=text>').attr({
        id: 'name',
        value: $(this).text()
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks :). it works much better. But the inputs are getting the same ID. How to I identify each input, whit different ID's so when uploading via AJAX, it will store the new informations correctly?

Comment: You could use `id: this.id` instead. In this context, `this` is the span so you can use that to access any of the properties or attributes of the span.

Answer (score 2):

replace this line:

```
$('span.editable').replaceWith($('<input type=text>').attr({ id: 'name', value: $('span.editable').text() }));
```

with:

```
$('span.editable').each(function(index, obj){
    $(obj).replaceWith($('<input type=text>').attr({ id: 'name', value: $(obj).text() }));
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {

    $(this).text("Change").attr('class', 'change');

    $('span.editable').each( function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($('<input type="text">').attr({ id: $(this).attr("id"), value: $(this).text() }));
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rMBd8/)